# Errors compiling OpenCV 2.4.12 with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, visual-studio-2015, computer-vision

I've downloaded OpenCV 2.4.12 source code. I've created a Visual Studio 2015 project of OpenCV with CMake to compile the library. Here is the CMake generation config:

[image]

While compiling OpenCV with Visual Studio 2015, I'm getting these errors:

[image]

I've searched too many times about this problem, but could not find a solution. Does anyone have an idea about what is the problem of compiling OpenCV 2.4.12 with Visual Studio 2015?

- Note 1: OpenCV 2.4.12 does not have pre built binaries/libraries for Visual Studio 2015, so that I have to compile it by myself.
- Note 2: OpenCV 3.1.0 can be compiled successfully with Visual Studio 2015.
- Note 3: I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with Update 2.

Answer (score 1):

it is not a complete answer but the error messages are about performance tests which you don't need them.You can disable performance tests build like seen in the following screenshot of cmake.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Now, it seems no errors occured. Do you have any idea about the errors?